# How to Print Newline

Tags: ruby, sinatra, newline

I'm trying to build a simple web server with Ruby Sinatra that respond with your current IP + current time (in HTML). It worked perfectly fine, it's just that I'm not sure how to display the output (my current IP and my current Time) into separated lines.

The following is my code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'socket'
addr_infos = Socket.ip_address_list
final_ip = ''
addr_infos.each do |addr_info|
    final_ip = final_ip + ' ' + addr_info.ip_address
end
cur_time = Time.now.ctime
get '/' do
    'Current Time: ' + cur_time + ', ' + 'Current IP Address: '+ final_ip
end
```

The output of my code is :

```
Current Time: Thu May 20 18:02:30 2021, Current IP Address: *IP NUMBER*
```

Can somebody help me with this? I'm new to Ruby Sinatra. Thanks!

Comment: In HTML you'd use [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) to add a line break

Comment: @Stefan so how do I add <br> to my code?

Comment: Use `'<br>'` instead of `', '`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag for a line break is [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) which can be used instead of the comma:

```
get '/' do
  'Current Time: ' + cur_time + '<br>' + 'Current IP Address: '+ final_ip
end
```

You can also use string interpolation:

```
get '/' do
  "Current Time: #{cur_time}<br>Current IP Address: #{final_ip}"
end
```

Or a [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29):

```
get '/' do
  <<~HTML
    Current Time: #{cur_time}<br>
    Current IP Address: #{final_ip}
  HTML
end
```

The line break after `<br>` is purely cosmetic.